# VBA Issue with nested do whiles and nested ifs

Tags: vba, excel

I have four columns, loop over two of the columns using nested do while loops, and then two if statements to act as constraints. If the two if statements are passed, revalue (paste is an option too), two new cells to the values of the cells that were checked using the index on the first loop, and another two new cells to the values of the cells that were checked using the index on the nested loop.

code:

```
Dim i
Dim j

i = 1
j = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Range("BE" & i))
    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("BH" & j))
        If Cells(i, "BE").Value = Cells(j, "BH").Value Then
            If (Cells(j, "BG").Value - Cells(i, "BF")) < TimeValue("1:00:00") Then
            'This is not correctly filtering, dates/time are in
            ' mm/dd/yy hh:mm format

                Range("BJ" & i).Value = Range("BE" & i).Value
                Range("Bk" & i).Value = Range("BF" & i).Value
                Range("BL" & i).Value = Range("BG" & j).Value
                Range("BM" & i).Value = Range("BH" & j).Value
            End If
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop

    i = i + 1
    j = 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

What it does:

It does almost everything correctly. The issue is that it does NOT correctly check if the difference in time between cells BG(j) and BF(i) < 60 minutes. Whether using:

```
If (Cells(j, "BG").Value - Cells(i, "BF")) * 1440 < 60 Then
```

or

```
IF (Cells(j, "BG").Value - Cells(i, "BF")) < TimeValue("1:00:00") Then
```

values that are 5 hours in difference are being seen as true and passing through the if statement.

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but changing `If ((Range("BG" & j).Value - Range("BF" & i) * 1440) < 60 Then` to `If (Range("BG" & j).Value - Range("BF" & i)) < TimeValue("1:00:00") Then` seems a little cleaner to me.

Comment: chancea: when operating in a 2 dimensional area I'm pretty sure I need two loops right?

FreeMan: I'll clean it up once it functions correctly, but thanks for that tidbit, didn't know about it!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `j = 1` just after `i = i + 1`

Comment: also you seem to have one not needed "(" in the If ((Range("BG" & j).Value - Range("BF" & i) * 1440) < 60 Then or im missing something

Comment: that fixed everything. You are my hero <3

Comment: no problem, if you could only mark as an answer :))

Comment: unfortunately I was wrong. It ended up copying everything and it seems like my if statements are done incorrectly since it didn't filter anything. Based on what I want to do I'm checking if BE(i) = BH(j) and they're both letters and numbers. And then the second if is checking if BG(j) - BF(i) < 1 hour (so I can use the conversion and then check in minutes) or how @FreeMan mentioned above. Any idea if I'm just dumb and what I'm missing here?